# How to get a single file from a folder in java?

Tags: java, file, scalability, directory

The idea is to take one single file, but I don't want to list all of the files. I have the address of the specified folder, but not the name.

Basically I want

findFileInFolder(String folderName) --- this method returns a random filename or the oldest file created on the folder

Has anybody ever tried doing this? Any ideas to avoid listing all of the files in an array and then taking the first one?

---

Added:

Just in case I wasn't clear (I'm really sorry for my English. Please forgive me if I sound prepotent or aggressive it is really not my intentions.) The file is not selected by a human, it's selected by the machine without asking or showing the file except for the method that returns a string with the FileName

String findFileInFolder(String folderName)

Like I comment is for usage of ram and processor because this is a secondary process and not the primary of the project, so if I have to read over a thousand files it will considerably reduce the performance of my project :(

Thanks ;)

---

Update: the program is running on different computers so if I could just access the directory not "thinking" about reading which file it would be great. =D

---

Hopefully last update: sorry for bothering you guys :)

From what I read on the answers there is no way. My question is: what good alternatives instead of doing an array would you think? My idea is to create an index in a textfile and to take only the first line.

Comment: What is wrong with reading the files into an array and then selecting one entry at random? There is usually no file system system method for 'give me a random file', so you'll have to find out which files are available anyway - by reading them into an array.

Comment: There is not an actuall problem, but I want to reduce the usage of ram to the minium, and the proccess of this section to the program too, if I have to list an array with over a thousand files it's a significative number

Comment: If you expect a lot of files in the directory, you could look at  java.nio.file.DirectoryStream

Comment: If I use that, wouldn't I have to read the whole Directory anyway? (really sorry for the english) and thanks for answering =(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I decidee to use this code, is not exactly what I wanted but it works for now.

```
  public static String getFileToCrawl(String directory){
      File dir = new File(directory);

      String[] children = dir.list();
      if (children == null) {
          return "";
      } else {
          int i=0;
          String filename = children[i];
          while (i<children.length && !filename.contains(".txt")){
              i++;
              filename = children[i];
          }
          return filename;
      }

  }
```

if anyone like it or know a way to improve this code it's really welcome ;) if you want to use it feel free :D

Answer (score 1):

You can have a look on [`FileFilter`](http://download-llnw.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/FileFilter.html) class and on the [`public File[] listFiles(FileFilter filter)`](http://download-llnw.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#listFiles%28java.io.FileFilter%29)

Using this method you will be able to filter files according to their last modification date for example.

On a side note, why do you want to avoid to list all the files, for performances concerns ?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way of doing this in current versions of java other than listing all files and selecting what you need. If you can use java 7, there is a [FileVisitor](http://java.sun.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/FileVisitor.html) class that can walk a folder tree without listing all of the files.

Comment: I can't =(, the other chooice that I do have is to make an index of files and removing one by one, but it wasn't my idea, I would like not having this magic file because it kills my performance too :-S

Comment: Have you ran any benchmarks about File.list() performance? It is a native method that returns only an array of file names, so thousand strings is not that much.

Comment: Thousands was just to say something, it's probably going to be lot's more and different proccess and computers running at the same time, I will add it in the info

Answer (score -1):

I realize this is an old thread but here is a quick and dirty way to do it:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;

public class Shuffle {
   public static void main(String[] argv) 
   throws Exception {

      File dir = new File(".");
      String[] children = dir.list();
      Collections.shuffle(Arrays.asList(children));
      System.out.println(children[0]);
   }   
}
```

Comment: This is exactly the *opposite* of what the OP asked, namely he says: "Any ideas to avoid listing all of the files in an array and then taking the first one?"

Comment: I’m not listing anything, merely selecting a random file from the folder.  Is that not what he asked for?

Comment: The line `String[] children = dir.list();` is doing the listing.